# How to create a schema and how to build relationship between tables in liferay dxp?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp, liferay-7.1

I have done many-many relation between Employee and Department table by using mapped-table attribute ,It was generated third table by name Employee_department, In Employee_department  table why liferay generate one extra column by name CompanyId  and it leads error in persistenceImpl class.

```
<service-builder package-path="com_m2" auto-namespace-tables="false">
    <namespace>emp</namespace>


   <entity name="Employee" local-service="true" remote-service="false" table="Employee" uuid="true">
        <column name="eid" type="long" primary="true"></column>
        <column name="name" type="String"></column>
        <column name="address" type="String"></column>
        <column name="deptid" type="Collection" entity="Department" mapping-table="Employee_department"/>
   </entity>
   
    <entity name="Department" local-service="true" remote-service="false" table="Department" uuid="true">
        <column name="deptid" type="long" primary="true"></column>
        <column name="department" type="String"></column>
        <column name="eid" type="Collection" entity="Employee" mapping-table="Employee_department"/>
    </entity>
    
</service-builder>

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

create table Employee_department (
    CompanyId LONG not null,
    deptid LONG not null,
    eid LONG not null,
    primary key (deptid, eid)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "company" in the Liferay API can be found as "Virtual Instance" on the UI: You can have multiple completely separate collections of data, for multi-tenancy.

I'm not sure why the field is generated when your two entities don't have such a field - that might be a bug. But it points to what you could do to blend your entities into Liferay's stock entities. This will make it easier to also use them from Liferay's Asset- and Info-Frameworks.

A whole new (and different) solution would be to leverage Liferay Objects and go with client-side code - but that's just here for completeness and not what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You defined two entities in `service.xml` but the service builder will create 3 tables and the third one is mapping tables which map the Employee and Department primary keys.

That table will hold the records of your employee and department respectively. So when you `getEmployeeDepartment(employeeId)` it will return the list of Departments and vice versa.

**UPDATE**
I was able to find the same error in this topic via the Liferay Dev community here https://liferay.dev/ask/questions/development/re-service-builder-persistance-impl-errors-in-case-of-tablemapper-5

The issue should be fixed after we add the column
`<column name="companyId" type="long" />` into both two entities.

Comment: Thanks for your response , That's right, But the thing is in third table implicitly generate one extra column by name CompanyId, that was not genereted by me.  Because of this i got error in persistanceImpl class.

Comment: @Override
 public void addEmployees(long pk, long[] employeePKs) {
  long companyId = 0;

  Department department = fetchByPrimaryKey(pk);

  if (department == null) {
   companyId = CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId();//------> this line //auto created in DepartmentpersistenceImpl class
  }
  else {
   companyId = department.getCompanyId();
  }

  departmentToEmployeeTableMapper.addTableMappings(
   companyId, pk, employeePKs);
 }

Comment: Error shows in      --->      CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId();                               this line

Comment: @Rakshithm companyId is an auto-generated parameter, it will be added/updated once a new record for Employee_department table is created/edited.

Comment: @Rakshithm can you post here what was the error on this line?
`companyId = CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId()`

Comment: In EmployeePersistenceImpl.java   it  shows error like [The method getCompanyId() is undefined for the type Employee]   .                                                                                      In  DepartmentPersistanceImpl.java    it shows like [The method getCompanyId() is undefined for the type Department]

Comment: Understood. @Rakshithm, could you add `<column name="companyId" type="long" />` into both two entities?

Comment: Same issue here: https://liferay.dev/ask/questions/development/re-service-builder-persistance-impl-errors-in-case-of-tablemapper-5

Comment: Thanks for quick response, Now its working , above one is the solution for generate third table in liferay. once again thanks for your response.

Comment: @Rakshithm if it is working for you, could you mark my answer is accepted so anyone who has the same issue could see it?